# Understanding an awk script

Tags: awk

I have the following awk script which I don't understand what it does or how to execute it properly.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
    first_start=$2;
    old_start=first_start;
    }
    {
        chr=$1;
        current_start=$2;
        if (current_start > (old_start + 1)) {
            print chr"\t"first_start"\t"old_start;
            first_start=current_start;
            old_start=first_start;
        }
        else {
            old_start=current_start;
        }
    }
    END {
        print chr"\t"first_start"\t"old_start;
    }' pileup.txt
```

The format of input should be:

```
NC_000001.10    11456   A   0   *   *
NC_000001.10    11467   A   1   ,   E
NC_000001.10    250133  t   2   ..  EA
NC_000001.10    250164  t   2   ..  EE
NC_000001.10    250169  t   2   ..  EE
```

I tried to execute it with `awk -f pileup_to_bed.awk` and got

```
awk: pileup_to_bed.awk:1: $ awk 'BEGIN{
awk: pileup_to_bed.awk:1:       ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: pileup_to_bed.awk:1: $ awk 'BEGIN{
awk: pileup_to_bed.awk:1:       ^ syntax error
```

Comment: It's not clear what your code is supposed to do. If you [edit] your question to provide the expected output given that sample input then we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are placing code in an `.awk` file then you need NOT to quote `'` for code(as far as I understood the problem), it should be like(`awk` file name is `script.awk`). I am removing `BEGIN{first_start=$2;old_start=first_start}` since it doesn't make sense to keep it in `BEGIN` section since no lines are getting read in it, thanks to Ed sir for pointing it out here.

```
    {
        chr=$1;
        current_start=$2;
        if (current_start > (old_start + 1)) {
            print chr"\t"first_start"\t"old_start;
            first_start=current_start;
            old_start=first_start;
        }
        else {
            old_start=current_start;
        }
    }
    END {
        print chr"\t"first_start"\t"old_start;
    }
```

When I run above like:

```
awk -f script.awk Input_file
```

I get following output:

```
NC_000001.10
NC_000001.10    11456   11456
NC_000001.10    11467   11467
NC_000001.10    250133  250133
NC_000001.10    250164  250164
NC_000001.10    250169  250169
```

Comment: when I execute with `awk -f script.awk pileup` I get `awk: script.awk:1: cat script.awk
awk: script.awk:1:           ^ syntax error`

Comment: @EliranTurgeman, no need to put `cat script.awk` in your `.awk` file, I mentioned to show the contents remove that line then you could try executing it, let me know how it goes then?